# Migrated GPG key does not allow decrypting GPG file

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I migrated from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 22.04.

I exported my private GPG key doing this from Windows:

```
gpg --export-secret-keys KEY_ID_HERE > private.key
```

Then imported it into Ubuntu doing:

```
gpg --import private.key
```

I also imported my public key doing:

```
gpg --import public.pub
```

I also imported the public key from the file sender (the person who is sending me an encrypted GPG file).

When I try to decrypt a file sent by that sender (which works on Windows), it returns:

```
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID 0A28D2E41CB2EA1C
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID 7CA26BE68DE3ABD7
gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit RSA key, ID 424757BE2B1F41CD, created 2021-12-07
      "Sender name <sender@email.com>"
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

The same happens for all previous files sent by this user.

One thing to note is that my name in the key, on Windows displayed as "Álvaro" and now displays as "Alvaro". Don't know if that may have something to do.

I also tried removing the passphrase. Anyway, pinentry is working fine.

I don't understand this error and how to fix it. I have all public and private keys I need.

Comment: Does `gpg -K` on the two systems agree that you have all keys you need?

Comment: @user1686 Thanks. When I run `gpg -K`, it returns my key name (the secret one), nothing else. When I run `gpg -k` it returns the public keys (mine and the sender's one)